# Accessing s3 from java aws lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

I'm trying to list keys on an S3 bucket from an AWS Lambda function written in Java. Running the code locally works fine (with hardcoded credentials).

When running the same Java code in Lambda, it hangs at `listObjects`

```
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials("XXXXXXXXXXXx",
           "XXXXXXXXXXZZZZZZZZZZz"));


ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
        .withBucketName(bucketName)
        .withMaxKeys(10);
ObjectListing objectListing;

do {
    objectListing = s3client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
```

The hardcoded user credentials and the Lambda execution role both have full access to s3.

Why does the S3 access hangs without error? What permission configuration is wrong?

Running something comparable in Lambda with NodeJS works

Comment: How do you know it's hanging? And why are you hard-coding credentials when you don't need any - just rely on the assumed Lambda execution role.

Comment: If tried the assumed Lambda execution role (and later gave that role admin privileges, just in case). Log above listObjects is printed, log after listObjects is not reached. Executed locally listObjects needs about one second.

Comment: What is your Lambda function timeout? The default is 3 seconds. Also, do the CloudWatch logs show your Lambda function timing out?

Comment: I'm using 60 seconds, yes cloud watch shows the timeout error

Comment: Event simpler commands are not returning: System.out.println("start");s3client.doesBucketExist(bucketName);System.out.println("stop"); (stop is not shown)

Comment: Seems odd. May be worth starting from scratch using the Getting Started example at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-gs.html and then add a simple S3 action like listBuckets (cutdown version of http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-wt-s3-log-event-data.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92207/discussion-between-jarmod-and-user85155).

Comment: The solution might be to switch to 512MB (was using 128MB), AWS is monitoring max usage of 66MB, with 512MB it is not hanging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to give the Lambda more memory to work with. For most runs Lambda report arround 111 MB for the execution of the simple S3 `listObjects` command. So 128 MB was not enough, with 512MB it works fine.

Comment: The problem was not that it ran out of memory, but that it did not complete within the configured Lambda timeout. Increasing the RAM size has the side effect of also, proportionally, increasing the available CPU as well as increasing your Lambda's share of the underlying network bandwidth. All of which makes it run faster and, in your case, allows the S3 request to actually complete much quicker. But it's not the RAM size.